# Parametrization of ellipse and normal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

Parametrization of ellipse and normal vector

$$F = x^2 \mathbf i + 2x\mathbf j + z^2\mathbf k \\ C: \text{ellipse} \implies 4x^2 + y^2 = 4$$

I'm trying to find the normal-vector here. I see that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ and $x = r \cos(\theta) ,\ y = r \sin(\theta)$ and $z = z$.

Is then $r = r \cos(\theta) + r \sin(\theta) + z$ ?

What is then the normal vector?

Comment: An ellipse is a curve : if you consider it as a one dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then a normal vector lies in the orthogonal of the plane containing the ellipse. But if you're talking about an ellipsoid (two dimensional manifold) then the answer is not trivial as before ; but in this case, a parametrization will be $\left(a\sin\theta\cos\phi,b\sin\theta\sin\phi,c\cos\theta\right)$ with reals $a,b,c$ and with $0<\theta<\pi$ and $0<\phi<2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
[image]
This is the question. Using Stokes’ Theorem to i have tof ind Line Integral

I find that curl F is 2k.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which plane you're stating that your ellipse is in, but I'll assume it's in the $xy$-plane ($z=0$).

Then your parametrization should be $\mathbf r(t) = (2\cos(t), \sin(t),0)$ for $0 \le t \le 2\pi$.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by the normal vector, but I'm going to guess that you mean the vector normal to the plane that contains the ellipse.  That'll just be any scalar multiple of $\mathbf n = (0,0,1)$ because $\langle (2\cos(t), \sin(t),0), (0,0,1)\rangle = 0$.